# How to iterate through the attributes of a feature in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, esri-leaflet

I receive polygons via the *ESRI REST API* with *Leaflet*. I want to iterate through all attributes of a feature in order to create a custom pop-up for it.

My code looks like this:

```
myLayer.on('click', function (evt) 
{
   feature = evt.layer.feature;
   //Here I want to iterate ...
}
```

I know that I can access the attributes like this:

```
feature.properties.myAttribute
```

But how can I iterate through all attributes?

Comment: with forEach function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you want to read all properties of the given event layer, without knowing in advance which properties are set and available?

In that case, this is a simple JavaScript problem, for which you can use [`Object.keys(feature.properties)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the array of available "attributes" in `feature.properties`. Then simply iterate over that array:

```js
myLayer.on('click', function (evt) {
    var feature = evt.layer.feature,
        props = feature.properties,
        attrs = Object.keys(props),
        attribute, value;

    for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i += 1) {
        attribute = attrs[i];
        value = props[attribute];
        // use the value to do something...
    }
});
```

You could also use the [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```js
for (attribute in props) {
    value = props[attribute];
}
```